# Why my comparison of two dates doesn't work as it should?

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

I have two dates (`date` and `NSDate()`) that I want to compare based on their day. When I do the following:

```
println(NSDate())
println(date)
println(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(date, toDate: NSDate(), toUnitGranularity: .DayCalendarUnit) == .OrderedSame)
```

I get this in the output:

```
2015-04-27 04:16:49 +0000
2015-04-26 23:57:35 +0000
true
```

It's clear (at least on the output) that the days are different but the `compareDate` method says there are the same.

Somebody can explain me why please?

Comment: They are different days in London (`+0000`) but they are the same day where _you_ are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you output a date, don't use simple `println`, which gives you the date/time in London. Instead, do it like this:

```
println(date.descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale()))
```

That will give you a clearer idea of what date-time is involved, because it will correspond to where you are located.

If you do that with your dates, you will find that they are in fact situated within the same day.

Comment: Actually +0 is UTC - London is currently +1

Comment: @Paulw11 you are even more pedantic than I am!

Comment: I thought I would repay you for catching me out earlier  :)